# Is there a built-in function to keep a number in certain range in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does something like this exist in python library?

```
def func(num, start, end):
    if num <= start:
        return start
    if num >= end:
        return end
    return num
```

Comment: You already have it, and it's easy to make. So why need a built-in?

Comment: @aIKid Because reinventing the wheel is not pythonic?

Answer (score 9):

`min` and `max` approach

```
def func(num, start, end):
    return min(max(num, start), end)
```

Or the ternary approach

```
def func(num, start, end):
    return num if start<num<end else start if num<=start else end
```

Comment: The ternary approach should be `start < num < end`

Comment: @thefourtheye: good point. Updated!

Comment: If there isn't a built-in, it doesn't matter how to write it for something so trivial.

Comment: There isn't a built-in that I'm aware of

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can come  up with is:

```
def func(num, start, end):
   return min(max(start,num),end)
```

But given some of the people that I work with better might be:

```
def func(num, start, end):
    """ Clip a single value """
    top, bottom = max(start, end), min(start, end)
    return min(max(bottom,num),top)
```

But if you have several values in an array there is always `numpy.clip`